# How to save global variables in an extern file in Python?

Tags: python, variables, store, argparse, flags

I'm looking for **a clean way to use global variables in many files**. So I want to write a parameters.py file where all my parameters will be stored.

How can i achieve this ? I've heard about `FLAGS` or `argparse` but i don't understand how to use them. Can someone explain me how to build this logic and then how to use it to import a variable.

I want to use the **standards of Tensorflow** if possible ...

Comment: perosnally and i knwo that's not what you asked, i use a csv file with name of varaible as name of columns. It's simpler that anything else (but not the best way to do it)

Comment: @Alexis You should look at blhsing's answer much, much simpler than having a two line CSV file.

Comment: indeed! but if you want to update those Global Variables, i don't know if it's possible with a setting.py (or at least i don't know how to do it). i'll look into it, thx for the notification!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply build a `settings.py` module where all variables defined in it are global:

```
var1 = 'value1'
var2 = 'value2'
...
```

And then in the other scripts or modules of the same project, you can simply refer to these global variables with:

```
import settings
print(settings.var1)
print(settings.var2)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a configuration file with a well known format:

- [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)
- [yaml](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)
- [toml](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml)

Then you can bring in variables like so

```
with open('path/to/config/file.json') as f:
    global_vars = json.load(f)

setting1 = global_vars['setting1']
# etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use configparser

params.ini:

```
[SECTION1]
var1 = 55
```

main.py

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('params.ini')
var = config["SECTION1"]["var1"]
```